# Java Priority Queue with a custom anonymous comparator

Tags: java, priority-queue

Forgive me if this is a tried question, but I'm having a little difficulty figuring it out.

I currently have a class Node, and each 'node' is a square in a maze. I'm trying to implement the A* algorithm, so each of these nodes will have an f-cost (int) data member inside of it. I was wondering if there's a way that I can create a priority queue of these nodes, and set up the f-cost variable as the comparator?

I've looked at examples online, but all I can find are String priority queues. Can I implement Comparator for the Node class? Would this allow me to access the data member stored inside it?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Absolutely.

You can use a `PriorityQueue` based on an anonymous `Comparator` passed to the constructor:

```
int initCapacity = 10;
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(initCapacity, new Comparator<Node>() {
    public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
        // compare n1 and n2
    }
});
// use pq as you would use any PriorityQueue
```

If your `Node` class already implements `Comparable` you don't even need to define a new `Comparator`, as that order will be used by default. Barring any other method, the natural ordering between objects will be used.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I was just having a little difficulty figuring out the override bit, you've made it clear!

Comment: Hi @YuvalAdam could you give an example of PriorityQueue using a lambda Comparator?

Answer (score 9):

This question was answered a while ago and I want to give some new options that are available.

1) Using lambda in case if your `Node` class doesn't implement Comparator interface and you don't want (or can't) add it:

```
  new PriorityQueue<>((node1, node2) -> Integer.compare(node1.getCost(), node2.getCost()));
```

2) Simple reverse order approach (require Node to implement Comparator interface):

```
  new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

3) Using utility function:

```
  new PriorityQueue<>(NodeUtil::customCompare);

  public static int customCompare(Node n1, Node n2) {
       return Integer.compare(n1.getCost(), n2.getCost());
  }
```

Comment: Great answer, can you please also explain what is the `NodeUtil` you used in the 3rd approch.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{

    public int compareTo(Node o) {
         // your comparative function
         return 0;
    }
```

}

if compareTo returns a negative int, it means "less than", 0 means "equals", 1 means "greater than"

that one function is all you need to be able to use PriorityQueue.

EDIT: comparison is other way, i messed that up. -1 < | 0 = | 1 > i alreays read those right to left for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty much on track except for the compare bits, and the +ve, -ve makes it clear.

Love the Invader Zim avatar btw ^^

Comment: Be careful, the comparison turns out to be "backwards": lower-ranked values are returned first.  It makes sense if you consider the priority queue a list sorted in ascending order, but it confused the hell out of me the first time I used one, as I expected the element with a priority of 100 to be "obviously" higher-ranked than the one with priority 30... ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadocs:

> An unbounded priority queue based on a
>   priority heap. This queue orders
>   elements according to an order
>   specified at construction time, which
>   is specified either according to their
>   natural order (see Comparable), or
>   according to a Comparator

Furthermore, PriorityQueues support generic data types.  Therefore, if you implement `Comparable` in your Node class, then you can create a `PriorityQueue<Node>` and use it normally.

Alternately, there is a constructor `PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)` that takes in a Comparator as part of the `PriorityQueue` constructor.  If you prefer this method, your node class does not need to contain the extra code needed when inheriting `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PriorityQueue class in java.util. You can use that and it will either use natural ordering (Node implements Comparable) or a comparator supplied in the constructor (if you don't want that code inside your Node class). Any class can access any data inside another as long as you allow it either by making a field non-private (potentially bad OOP style) or supplying an accessor method public int getG(), public int getH(), public int getF().